# Redirect user on login based on session variable

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, redirect

In my zend project I have this code in header.phtml which is loaded into every layout / view. It's the start of a function which sets a div based on the users session. I need to add a redirect based on these variables. So that any page (controller) the user tries to access they'll be redirected to the billing controller index action. I know I can set the redirect in each controllers index action but that is a lot of code. Is there anyway I cand add the redirect into my header.phtml?

Thanks

```
<?php
$userSess= new Zend_Session_Namespace('Default');
if(isset($userSess->subscription_state) && isset($userSess->account_type)){
    if($userSess->subscription_state == "unpaid" && $userSess->account_type == 1){ 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The kind of thing you are doing is probably done best in a [Front Controller Plugin](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3372).

By handling your testing in layout, your have already eaten the cost of processing a request and rendering a view, just to throw it away by redirecting.

In contrast, performing these checks at some early point in the dispatch cycle - at `preDispatch()`, for example - you never have to load a controller and process the action.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David Weinraub. You can do this in your own Front Controller plugin for example:

```
<?php

class My_Controller_Plugin_Abc extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract{

 public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){

        $userSess= new Zend_Session_Namespace('Default');
        if(isset($userSess->subscription_state) && isset($userSess->account_type)){
            if($userSess->subscription_state == "unpaid" && $userSess->account_type == 1){ 
                    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect("/index/login")->sendResponse();
            }
         }

 }

}
```

And Register plugin in Bootstrap.php

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();    
$frontController->registerPlugin(new My_Controller_Plugin_Abc());
```